# multiplying integer values by 10 in a formula in SQL server server

Tags: sql-server

I have a dimension field in a table which has values like

```
40x44+(12), 50x63+10(0), 65x88+0, 16+8x41.
```

Irrespective of the arithmetic operators, I need to multiply the values with 10 and retain the formula as it is.

The above values should be

```
400x440+(120), 500x630+100(0), 650x880+0, 160+80x410
```

after multiplied by 10.

Please help me how can I achieve this in SQL server 2008.

Comment: And your dimension field is of string type?

Comment: Yes, its nvarchar field..

Comment: Then it's really difficult to get it done @ DB end. Try doing this @ application code.

Comment: Are you even sure you want this and not, say, simply multiply the whole formula by 10 (`T` -> `(T)x10`, which is easy to do in SQL)? Multiplying each individual number by 10 is a peculiar operation; I'm not sure what the use case for that is.

Comment: Actually the dimension values are in 'Cms'..which needs to be converted to 'mm'. The dimension field is a formula for some article specification. So the whole formula cannot be multiplied by 10 ...either we need to append 0 to each individual value or multiply by 10..please help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the trick as long as you do not have @ in your text. Otherwise chose another end character:

Create this function:

```
CREATE function [dbo].[f_splitx]
(
@param nvarchar(2000)
)
returns nvarchar(2000)
as
begin
declare @rv nvarchar(2000) = ''
;with a as
(
  select 
    cast(@param + '@' as nvarchar(2000)) f, 
    cast(null as nvarchar(2000)) g, 
    1 t, 
    1 seq
  union all
  select 
    cast(stuff(f, 1, t-1, '') as nvarchar(2000)), 
    left(f, t-1), 
    patindex(case when stuff(f, 1, t-1, '') 
      like '[0-9]%' then '%[^0-9]%' else '%[0-9@]%' end, 
    stuff(f, 1, t-1, '')),
    seq + 1
  from a
  where t > 1 or seq = 1
)
select @rv +=
  case when g like '[0-9]%' then cast(g* 10 as varchar(20)) else g end
from a
where seq > 2
return @rv
end
```

Execute like this:

```
SELECT dbo.f_splitx('40x44+(12), 50x63+10(0), 65x88+0, 16+8x41.')
```

Result:

```
400x440+(120), 500x630+100(0), 650x880+0, 160+80x410.
```

Or execute like this:

```
SELECT dbo.f_splitx(val)
FROM (values('40x44+(12)'), ('50x63+10(0)'), ('65x88+0'), ('16+8x41.')) x(val)
```

Result:

```
400x440+(120)
500x630+100(0)
650x880+0
160+80x410.
```

Comment: the function is splitting the text and multiplying the numerics by 10 and concatinating the values again